Combining Multiple Columns by order of Appearance
I have the following Excel Table:



Rank
Database 1
Database 2
Database 3
Database 4




1
Entry A
Entry C
Entry G
Entry C


2
Entry B
Entry A
Entry A
Entry D


3
Entry C
Entry F
Entry B
Entry E


4
Entry D
Entry B
Entry E
Entry A


5
Entry E
Entry D
Entry D
Entry G



I want to combine all those entries / columns into one column, depending on how often an entry has appeared and how high, if that makes sense.
I want to sort all unique distinct entries based on the rank appearances per database entry;
Rank 1 appearance means 1, Rank 2, 2; etc. if no appearances of an Entry in a database, they have a higher rank score than any listed rank scores.
In example data there are 5 ranks. So unlisted means 6, or more.
So with example data, Entry A appeared first in database 1, second in database 2, second in database 3 and fourth in database 4 it would get: 1+2+2+4 = 9 points.
My goal is to sort the entries by these calculated scores.
Doing it manually is obviously an option but A prone to Errors and B tedious, so I was wondering if there was some way to automate it.
I have only tried it by hand to be honest, not really sure how I should even go about this.

Can you give us an expected outcome? [edit] it into your original question.

Here's one way:
=LET(,_DB1,A1:A5,_DB2,B1:B5,_DB3,C1:C5,_DB4,D1:D5,
_DataSet,UNIQUE(VSTACK(_DB1,_DB2,_DB3,_DB4)),
_RefDB1,IFERROR(XMATCH(_DataSet,_DB1,,-1),6),
_RefDB2,IFERROR(XMATCH(_DataSet,_DB2,,-1),6),
_RefDB3,IFERROR(XMATCH(_DataSet,_DB3,,-1),6),
_RefDB4,IFERROR(XMATCH(_DataSet,_DB4,,-1),6),
_Stack,HSTACK(_RefDB1,_RefDB2,_RefDB3,_RefDB4),
_BRSum,BYROW(_Stack,LAMBDA(a,SUM(a))),
_Sort,SORTBY(_DataSet,_BRSum),
_Sort)

How it looks (H8:H12):

How it works: LET is a set of functions or arguments, so it's compact (Excel 365 only though).
_DBx is each of your databases called into the function;
_DataSet is a collection of all unique values;
_RefDBx then gives a score to each entry, with 6 being 'not found';
_Stack then stacks these rows of scores;
_BRSum sums each value, outputting the score;
_Sort sorts your initial dataset, in order of the values taken from _BRSum;

Would this work? (Assuming Microsoft 365)

Get all unique entries
For each entry assign rank by position within a column (XMATCH)
Rank is the sum of positions within all columns
show_ranks step is just to show the calculation, please remove it from VSTACK when it is no longer needed.

Update 2024-08-20: Parameterized not_found_rank: made this a parameter since different values can affect the sorting.
=LET(
    data, A1:D5,
    u_entries, SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(data))),
    col_index, SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(data)),
    rank_by_pos_in_col, LAMBDA(entry, not_found_rank,
        IFNA(
            MAP(col_index, LAMBDA(c, XMATCH(entry, INDEX(data, , c)))),
            not_found_rank
        )
    ),
    show_ranks, LAMBDA(not_found_rank,
        REDUCE(
            EXPAND({"Entry", "Rank", "Col Pos"}, , COLUMNS(data) + 2, ""),
            u_entries,
            LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                VSTACK(
                    acc,
                    HSTACK(
                        cur,
                        SUM(rank_by_pos_in_col(cur, not_found_rank)),
                        rank_by_pos_in_col(cur, not_found_rank)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    entry_rank, TAKE(DROP(show_ranks(ROWS(data) + 1), 1), , 2),
    sorted, SORT(entry_rank, 2),
    IFNA(VSTACK(show_ranks(ROWS(data) + 1), "== Sorted ==", sorted), "")
)



=LET(a,A1:D5,b,UNIQUE(TOCOL(a)),SORT(HSTACK(b,MAP(b,LAMBDA(u,SUM(BYROW(a,LAMBDA(r,SUM(FILTER(COLUMN(r),r=u,COLUMNS(r)+1)))))))),2))
This sums the matched column number for each unique possible entry row wise.
If not found in a row, it adds up the column numbers +1 for that row.
If your column doesn't start in A:A  you need to decrease the column number with x like COLUMN(r)-x
This solution includes all entries per row. So row 2 Entry A is for column B and C.
Edit I see I misread the order (by column instead by row):
=LET(a,A1:D5,b,UNIQUE(TOCOL(a)),SORT(HSTACK(b,MAP(b,LAMBDA(u,SUM(BYCOL(a,LAMBDA(r,SUM(FILTER(ROW(r),r=u,ROWS(r)+1)))))))),2))
Same logic, but using BYCOL/ROW(S).
Leaving out the actual counts:
=LET(a,A1:D5,b,UNIQUE(TOCOL(a)),SORTBY(b,MAP(b,LAMBDA(u,SUM(BYCOL(a,LAMBDA(r,SUM(FILTER(ROW(r),r=u,ROWS(r)+1)))))))))
Or, in case there are no duplicates per column:
=LET(a,A1:D5,b,UNIQUE(TOCOL(a)),SORTBY(b,MAP(b,LAMBDA(u,SUM(BYCOL(a,LAMBDA(r,IFNA(XMATCH(u,r),ROWS(r)+1))))))))
Or you could use the rank^10 to differentiate higher lower rankings better:
=LET(a,B2:E6,b,UNIQUE(TOCOL(a)),SORTBY(b,MAP(b,LAMBDA(u,SUM(BYCOL(a,LAMBDA(r,IFNA(XMATCH(u,r),ROWS(r)+1)^10)))))))

Have you tried COUNTIF in a separate column for each variation of entry?
That will give you overall frequencies across the array in a new array you can hide later; and in that array based on the row you can add a "bonus" value into the formula (I just applied the rank number as in your example rank 1 was worth fewer points) to indicate rank like you suggested?
Then you could then find your results across that array per entry and per rank?
There might well be an easier way but that's my first thought.
ExampleTable1
